# Prove a solution of an ODE is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prove this statement:

"Let $f$ be a continuous function locally Lipschitz in the second variable in $(a,b) \times \mathbb{R}$.Suppose that there exists a continuous function $g$ defined in $(a,b)$ so that $|f(x,y)| \leq g(x) \,\, \forall \, \, (x,y) \in (a,b) \times \mathbb{R}$. Prove that all solutions of the ODE $y'=f(x,y)$ are defined in $(a,b)$.

I have thought the following:
*From the first conditions, it is deduced by Picard the unicity of the solutions.

*By the Mean Value Theorem and the fact that $y'=f(x,y)$, we could state that $|y(b)-y(a)|=|y'(c)||b-a| \leq |g(c)||b-a|$, for some $c \in (a,b)$.

The thing is I don't know how to use that $g$ is defined in $(a,b)$ to prove that all solutions also are defined in $(a,b)$. Thanks.

Comment: $g$ is continuous and thus has a maximum over $[a,b]$.

Comment: Oh, it's true @LutzLehmann , by Weierstrass. So if that maximum is $M$, then $|y(b)-y(a)|\leq M |b-a|$. Therefore $|y(b)-y(a)|$ is bounded, so it doesn't go to infinity. So this would be enough to prove the solution is defined? Unicity is not used?

Comment: Yes, that is sufficient. Using uniqueness for bounds is a finer tool, for instance if constant solutions are known. I'm not sure in the moment if it is necessary to use it for bounds from differential inequalities.

Comment: Alright, so, in general for the solution of an ODE, bounded in an interval implies defined in that interval, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, because of the theorem on the maximal solution. So if you have a box, it has to leave the box. And if that can not happen towards top or bottom due to bounds on the solution, then it has to be to the sides at the ends of the time interval.